# nginx reverse proxy gateway not behaving with ssl

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, ssl, reverse-proxy

port 80 on the web server destination serer `192.168.0.43` works in every way: gateway and inside the lan. Perfect.

I have the certbot certs on the gateway `192.168.0.60` generating perfectly

the domain points to the gateway outward facing ip i.e. `192.168.0.60` has an outward facing IP and listens on port 80 and port 443 for the domain madeupexample.com

this is the gateway nginx conf on `192.168.0.60`

```
server{
# SSL configuration
#
        listen 443 ssl default_server;
        listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;

        server_name madeupexample.com www.madeupexample.com;

        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.madeupexample.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.madeupexample.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
        include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://192.168.0.43;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }


        error_page 404 /404.html;
                location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
                location = /50x.html {
        }
}

server {
   listen 80;

   server_name madeupexample.com www.madeupexample.com;

    if ($host = madeupexample.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = www.madeupexample.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

   return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

this used to work fine

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name madeupexample.com www.madeupexample.com;

    location / {
         proxy_pass http://192.168.0.43;
    }
}
```

what am I doing wrong? the domain just spins

Comment: `the domain just spins`? Please provide actual error messages you encounter.

Comment: the domain `https://www.madeupexample.com` and the 80 version `http://www.madeupexample.com` spin in the browser until  the browser says `Connection has timed out`. If I change the nginx conf back to the port 80 only version it works immediately for `http://www.madeupexample.com` only however.

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall issue.

Comment: you're right I didn;t know `ufw http` didn't also add `ufw https` thank you it's fixed